Text Color in QGIS Map Tip
I am trying to use Map Tip in QGIS 3.34.6.  I have everything working and showing the value of a field from the attribute table of a layer but the tips appear with black text on a dark grey background which is unreadable unless I put my face very close to the screen.
I have done many searches including the online QGIS manual but have found hardly anything about map tips at all and only one answer that addresses the question of styling for map tips using HTML but the solution given does not work, possibly because it is now 7 years old and relates to QGIS 2
It seems that I am probably missing some critical formatting code, but I cannot figure it out.

Did you find the section in the official documentation?

related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240084/styling-the-map-tips-pop-up-box-with-css-background-color-not-working

What is your code currently?
